# Fetch All Records against id's in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I retrieve the data from database the output is following
[image]

I want to fetch records against these id's but when I try in my controller with for each it gives me only 1 record back
Here is my code

```
//fetch all the posts relative to user in session
    $post_id['id'] = $this->message_model->get_post($id);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($post_id['id']);die;
     foreach ($post_id['id'] as $key) {

        $post_id    =     $key['post_id'];
        $results['post_list'] = $this->Model_Frontend_Posts->get($post_id);
    }
```

when i print `$results['post_list']` it gives me only one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in an array so that it doesn't overrides on every loop. I guess this should solve it -

```
$results['post_list'][] = $this->Model_Frontend_Posts->get($post_id);
```

instead of

```
$results['post_list'] = $this->Model_Frontend_Posts->get($post_id);
```

Comment: then how I access this in my view mean kindly can u explain a little bit more about to break it using for each like for each( $results['post_list'] as $key ) is it right way ????

Comment: kindly guide me how I view the data is my for each is right because with this it becomes multidimensional array how i break it

Comment: the foreach you've written is correct as I suspect. If it doesn't work out, you're free to ask another question on this site :-) with a little bit explanation of what expected output you need

Comment: if(!empty($post_list)){
        foreach ($post_list as $key => $value) {?>

Comment: Paste the error you get in the new question you ask if not already solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
$post_id['id'] = $this->message_model->get_post($id);
 $array = array_column($post_id['id'], 'post_id'));
     foreach ($array as $value) {
        $results['post_list'] = $this->Model_Frontend_Posts->get($value);
    }
```

Better to use array_column from the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php